# Getting issue "Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)" when I am running following command - $sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

Tags: java, linux

Getting issue "Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)" when I am running following command -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

when I run

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I get

> Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer

This was a change in Oracle JDL Licence agreement. https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

I was setting up the Ubuntu VM machine on cloud.  What should be a workaround?

Comment: You need to run `apt-get update` after adding the repository.

Comment: I did that. It seems to me that I need to download the JDK manually by accepting the agreement with Oracle.

Comment: If you’re not fussed you should probably not use the Oracle JDKs and install OpenJDK instead.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason to use JDK 8, you may try 11. Have you tried using PPA from [linuxuprising](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/10/how-to-install-oracle-java-11-in-ubuntu.html)?

If JDK 11 works for you, you can use this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer
```

And for the JDK 12 you can use from the same source again ([here is the link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-12-jdk-12-in.html)), or basically do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java12-installer
```